# How to style only a sub-class with .css?

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons on my page:

```
<a class="paginate_button next" id="myTable_next" tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="1" aria-controls="myTable">Next</a>

<a class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="MyTable_previous" tabindex="0" data-dt-idx="1" aria-controls="myTable">Previous</a>
```

Now, I want all paginate_buttons to have the same styling, but if they're a next button, they float right, if they're a previous button, they float left, and if they're disabled, they're invisible.

Below is the .CSS I thought would achieve this, however, when my button has class 'disabled' it is still visible. I feel that the .next .disabled class changing is the issue, but I don't know what the correct syntax is.

```
.paginate_button{
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
*cursor: hand;
color: #333333 !important;
border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.paginate_button .next{
float: right;
}

.paginate_button .previous{
float: left;
}

.paginate_button .next .disabled{
visibility: hidden;
}

.paginate_button .previous .disabled{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Just remove space between selectors like this

```
.paginate_button.next{--- your code ---}
.paginate_button.previous{--- your code ---}
```

**Explanation:**

Case 1:

If both the selectors are of **same element** like this:

```
<div class="selector1 selector2"> some code </div>
```

Then you have to use them **without space** like this:

```
.selector1.selector2{--- your code ---}
```

Case 2:

If both the selectors are of **different element** like this:

```
<div class="selector1">
   <p class="selector2"> some code </p>
</div>
```

Then you have to use them **with space** like this:

```
.selector1 .selector2{--- your code ---}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove spaces between selectors:

```
.paginate_button.next{

...

.paginate_button.previous {

...
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

Simply omit the spaces like this:

```
.paginate_button.next{
float: right;
}
```

Putting a space as you did means any element of class next that is a descendant of (contained within) an element of class paginate_button. Without the space you specify an element that both of class paginate_button and next.

Answer (score -3):

add commas and remove the paginated_button on the next,previous,disabled

```
.next{
float: right;
}

.previous{
float: left;
}

.disabled{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Now you made all buttons disappear.

Comment: dont just minus answer without them fixing their answers. you dont even know what your codes doing...

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. That's why it is "minused".

Comment: I think the problem with your answer is that now all elements with the disabled class will be invisible, whereas I just want the ones that have paginate_button *and* disabled classes. My question was about how to chain these two together.